# What part of speech is "down" in "down went the Titanic"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> **Down** went the Titanic.

What part of speech is *down* in this context? I have to choose between a) Preposition, b) Noun, c) Verb, and d) Adjective. But I think the correct answer should be "adverb", which is absent from the list.

What do you think about it?

Comment: When you say "have to choose," what do you mean?  Is this homework or a test question?

Answer (score 4):

*Go down* is a phrasal verb meaning ‘sink’. It’s made up of the verb *go* and the adverbial particle *down*. Adverbial particles normally follow the verb, but they can, as here, be placed before it for emphasis.

Comment: So you think this is an Adverb

Comment: That might be one way to analyse it, but you can’t really separate _down_ form _went_.  In this sentence they form a single semantic unit. In any case, _down_ is here neither a preposition nor a noun nor an adjective.

Comment: @BarrieEngland - Is "to go down" really a phrasal verb?  Or would the term compound verb be more appropriate? I think a phrasal verb is a  verb composition whose meaning you can't find out from the basic meaning of verb and compound particle. -I agree with you that "down" in "to go down" is an adverbial particle; that's the traditional term in grammars.  - In "Down went the Titanic" we have a stylistic inversion. I would say not so much for emphasis, but to convey a certain dynamics.

Comment: @rogermue In my opinion, a true phrasal verb is a verb and particle combination in which the two form a semantic unit AND the particle can move around in the sentence.  "Take off," is a good example.  Take off your shoes, or take your shoes off.  If the particle can't move or is "locked." It's not part of a phrasal verb.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - This is not the traditional use of the term phrasal verb. That the particle can be movable is a separate feature that has nothing to do with phrasal verbs. -https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb

Comment: Go down is not a phrasal verb.  In the sentence "they went down the stairs." "down the stairs" is a prepositional phrase.  It is not possible to say, "They went the stairs down."  or "Down they went the stairs."  How about "went up" or "went across?"  Are those phrasal verbs, too?

Comment: @rogermue Ok, it seems you have a background in linguistics and language teaching.  Can you help me understand the difference between "She made up the story" (I feel "made up" is a true phrasal verb) and "She went up to the teacher." (went up is not a phrasal verb here.). Perhaps I am mistaken in my understanding.

Comment: Yes, I would also see "to make up" in the sense of to invent as a phrasal verb. And in "She went up to the teacher"  we have verb in its normal meaning and use and a where-to indication.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look and examples.

1. The Titanic went down  (went is a verb ,  down is a adverb)
2. Now let's reverse the sentence.....
3. Down went the Titanic     (Down is still an adverb)

Answer (score 0):

English is full of tricks:

*down went the Titanic*, *up went the flag*, *out went the dog*, *up flew the parrot*, *in came the students**, *out came the whip*, for example.

**The *phrasal verbs* here would be**: go down, go up, go out, fly up/down, come in/out.

**You can take the preposition and place it in front of the main verb.**

Generally, down, up and out, etc. would come after the verb. This is either poetic or funny or emphatic in some way.

- When I opened the kitchen door, out went the dog running and barking.

The emphasis I wanted here was to stress the outbound movement.

**Mostly, these will be phrasal verbs that have been used in this manner**.

There are many more but I can't be expected to come  up with every one of them.

Even, for example, in sailing: a sailboat is said to come around (change direction when it is on the wind).

- Around came the boat, and all the students knew enough to change sides.

For reference on [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs)

Bear in mind that a real phrasal verb is not a verb and a prepositional phrase, that is somewhat different. (The dog went down the stairs.)